# Python printing only first line

Tags: python

New to Python. 
Using this code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
with open('/tmp/cadrootcomp1.firstwords',mode="rb") as f:
    print '/'.join(f.read().split('/')[:2]) + '/'
```

Get output:
abc/def/

when original line was abc/def/ghi

So this works fine. Need this script to run on other lines in file. It is processing only first line.

Comment: you need to use a loop to read all lines. `f.read()` reads one line at a time

Comment: New to python. Can you please show how this loop works?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand correctly what you are trying to do. If you are trying to iterate over lines in the file, try this.

```
with open('/tmp/cadrootcomp1.firstwords',mode="rb") as lines:
    for line in lines:
        print '/'.join(line.split('/')[:2]) + '/'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think below one is better. I guess you are using slicing to remove `\n` after `file.read()`. A better way to do it is to use `strip()` like this:

```
f.read().strip()
```

You don't even need that when reading line by line.

```
with open('/tmp/cadrootcomp1.firstwords',mode="rb") as f:
for line in f:
    print line.rsplit('/',1)[0] + '/'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
with open('/tmp/cadrootcomp1.firstwords',mode="rb") as f:
    for line in f:
        print '/'.join(line.split('/')[:2]) + '/'
```